# Laravel 4.2 How to convert my SQL code into Laravel standards

Tags: php, sql, laravel, latitude-longitude, radius

I would like to use my SQL code based on Laravel standards. This code works fine in my other project. I want to add this to my controller function and convert this SQL code to Laravel standards, in most simple way. Anyone knows how to do it?

Here's my codes:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS a.*, ( $distance_exp * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) 
                * cos( radians( lontitude ) - radians($long) ) 
                + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) 
                AS distance                             

                FROM {{driver}} a 
                HAVING distance < $max_radius           
                $and
                ORDER BY is_sponsored DESC, distance ASC
                LIMIT 0,100
```

So far here's what I have tried but still it's getting me an error prompt message:

```
public function val_getdistance() 
{
  //sample value
   $radius=3;
   $property = 
        Driver::select(
    DB::raw("title, latitude, longitude, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(:latitude) ) * 
    cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(:longitude) ) + 
    sin(radians(:lat_i) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance"),
    ["latitude" => $lat, "longitude" => $lng, "lat_i" => $lat])
->having("distance", "<", "$radius")
->orderBy("distance")
->take(20)
->setBindings([$lat, $lng, $lat,  $radius])
->get();

dd($property);
}
```

Comment: show us the error messages.

Comment: Undefined variable: lat

Comment: The only variable you have defined in `val_getdistance()` is `$radius` - `$lat` and `$lng` are not defined.  Did you mean to pass them in as parameters?  Or set them where you set `$radius`?

Comment: I want to set them as where my `$radius` are set.

Comment: Simple, define `$lat` and `$lng`

Comment: I want to set the value of  `$lat` and `$lng` queried from my table `Driver` (DB).

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the values to the function, so it might look like this, since `$lng` and `$lat` are not defined anywhere

```
public function val_getdistance($lng, $lat) 
{
  //sample value
   $radius=3;
   $property = 
        Driver::select(
    DB::raw("title, latitude, longitude, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(:latitude) ) * 
    cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(:longitude) ) + 
    sin(radians(:lat_i) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance"),
    ["latitude" => $lat, "longitude" => $lng, "lat_i" => $lat])
->having("distance", "<", "$radius")
->orderBy("distance")
->take(20)
->setBindings([$lat, $lng, $lat,  $radius])
->get();

dd($property);
}
```

With this declaration you'll be sending lng and lat (guessing you need them to be dynamic) to the function yourself, you can add any other parameter you need in the function declaration.
If you need static you can declare where `$radius` is, so just below/above radius add like this and the rest of your code stays unchanged:

```
$lng = 42.2039;
$lat = 29.3901;
```

or whatever the values you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want it to be dynamic the value of $lat and $lang retrived from my database.

Comment: Then use the first part of the code where you send $lat and $lng to function

Comment: Missing argument 1 for OwnerController::val_getdistance()

Comment: If the function declaration has 2 variables in it you need to send them when calling the function, e.g you use it inside the other function then you need to call it like val_getdistance($var1, $var2); where $var1 and $var2 will be values for your lat and lng (so after it's converted it'd look like this val_getdistance(23.9309,32.3903); ). For the variables you can get them any way you want, you can write another query for the 2nd table where you get lat/lng from (probably the best solution)